# algorithm for shifting the array element

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, search, data-structures

I need a algorithm which will pop the array element from the first index and push the next element (from the original array at last index) until the matching set of elements found.

Like below:

```
Original array : {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120}

1st iteration : 10,20,30,40
2nd iteration : 20,30,40,50
3rd iteration : 30,40,50,60
4th iteration : 40,50,60,70 .... and so on until the matching criteria set found.
```

Logic should iterate until the required set of array element found.(based on some calculations on elements)

Comment: This seems like quite a trivial problem, what code have you already tried?

Comment: Why dont you simply use a counter that increments by 1 till array.Length - 5

Comment: While you can modify the array, if you're just looking for a subset of 5 elements, there's no need to. Iterate through it using begin/end indexes 5 elements apart and/or leverage `ArraySegment` to do easy calculations on the set of 5.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is *vague one*; if you want to *shift* the starting point:

```
   int array = new[] {10,20,30,40,50};

   for (int shift = 0; shift < array.Length; ++shift) {
     for (int i = shift; i < array.Length; ++i) {
       int value = array[i];

       Console.Write(value);
       Console.Write(", ");
     }

     Console.WriteLine();  
   }
```

Outcome:

```
   10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 
   20, 30, 40, 50,
   30, 40, 50,
   40, 50,
   50,
```

If you want to *rotate* the array I suggest *modulo arithmetics*:

```
   for (int shift = 0; shift < array.Length; ++shift) {
     for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; ++index) {
       int i = (shift + index) % array.Length;  

       int value = array[i];

       Console.Write(value);
       Console.Write(", ");
     } 

     Console.WriteLine();   
   }
```

Outcome:

```
   10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 
   20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 
   30, 40, 50, 10, 20,
   40, 50, 10, 20, 30,
   50, 10, 20, 30, 40,
```